# how to add this external vue component in my laravel5.3 project?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, chart.js

I try to add http://gritcode.github.io/gritcode-components/#/wizard in my laravel 5.3 project but when i used its nothing showing in my view here is i'm getting console "Uncaught ReferenceError: gritcode is not defined"
my app.js is.

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
new Vue({ components: { 'vs-toast': gritcode-components.toast }})

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
});
```

and my welcome.blade.php

```
<div id="app">

  <vs-toast>

      <vs-wizard :current-index.sync="currentStep">
      <vs-wizard-step 
        title="Personal Information" 
        description="Enter your details"
        :progress="progress.step1" 
        icon="person">
      </vs-wizard-step>
      <vs-wizard-step 
        title="Payment" 
        description="Pay with credit card or Paypal" 
        :progress="progress.step2"
        icon="credit-card">
      </vs-wizard-step>
      <vs-wizard-step 
        title="Confirmation" 
        description="Your order details" 
        :progress="progress.step3"
        :disable-previous="true"
        icon="check">
      </vs-wizard-step>
    </vs-wizard>

  </vs-toast>

</div>
```

my package.json

```
  {
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
   "prod": "gulp --production",
  "dev": "gulp watch"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
   "babel": "^6.5.2",
     "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
   "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
   "gritcode-components": "^0.4.7",
   "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "jquery": "^3.1.0",
  "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
  "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
  "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
  "lodash": "^4.16.2",
  "vue": "^2.0.1",
  "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
  "vuestrap-base-components": "^0.8.10",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
   },
    "dependencies": {
     "vue-material-datepicker": "^2.0.1"
   }
   }
```

my gulpfile.js

```
    const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

      require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');



   elixir(mix => {
      mix.sass('app.scss')
      .webpack('app.js');
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the example says on the intro page you have to import them from a subdirectory of the plugin.

The example given on their website is for their `toast` component which has a default export, however, because `wizard` is made up of two components it uses named exports instead so the syntax for importing them is slightly different.

**Importing `default` export**

```
import foo from "someComponent"
```

**Importing `named` exports**

```
import {bar, baz} from "SomeOtherComponent"
```

So, for your situation you should be able to do:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import {wizard, wizardStep} from "gritcode-components/src/components/wizard";

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'vs-wizard': wizard,
        'vs-wizard-step': wizardStep
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @VipinKumar Could you edit your question and add the contents on your `gulpfile.js` and `package.json`?

Comment: i edited question and when use as you say in answered i did but i was getting errors "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Comment: @VipinKumar This plugin and `vue-strap` currently seem to incompatible with Vue2 so from that point alone I would suggest either building the components yourself or finding an alternative plugin. The plugin itself doesn't seem to be complex so you could use the source files found in your `node_modules/gritcode-components/src/components/wizard` to create your own `.vue` files (they will need updating for Vue2). Also, I read a post in the issues on github that the author wasn't planning on using vuestrap anymore and there doesn't seem to have been an update since then either.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and this worked for me.

```
import { wizard as vsWizard } from 'gritcode-components/dist/gritcode-components';
import { wizardStep as vsWizardStep } from 'gritcode-components/dist/gritcode-components';
import { toast as vsToast } from 'gritcode-components/dist/gritcode-components';
```

note that we are loading this from
    **"gritcode-components/dist/gritcode-components"**
not from 
    **"gritcode-components/src/components/wizard"** as suggested in one of the answers.

then in your Vue instance you can do something like this to load the components:

```
require('./bootstrap');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        vsWizard,
        vsWizardStep,
        vsToast
    },
    data: {
        currentStep: 0
    },
    computed: {
        progress: function() {
            return {
               step1: this.getStepPercentage(1),
               step2: this.getStepPercentage(2),
               step3: this.getStepPercentage(3)
            };
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getStepPercentage: function(stepNumber) {

                if (stepNumber == 1) {
                    //depending on your requirements you will return
                    //a value between 0 and 100 that describe
                    //the completion status of the step 1
                }

                if (stepNumber == 2) {
                    //depending on your requirements you will return
                    //a value between 0 and 100 that describes
                    //the completion status of the step 2
                }

                if (stepNumber == 3) {
                    //depending on your requirements you will return
                    //a value between 0 and 100 that describes the   
                    //completion status of the step 3
                }

        }
    }
});
```

Also in your question, you have two Vue instances: one for which you load the components, and another one bound to the element with id #app. The one with the #app element is the one that will be managing your html from the blade file. The problem you will run into, once this code loads is that you are adding the components on the Vue instance that is not bound to your #app div, and therefore the Vue instance designated for managing your #app element will not have access to them. So I suggest using only one instance of Vue like in the example above unless you have a good reason for using more

Lastly, I would advise you against wrapping your 'vs-wizard' tag element with 'vs-toast', unless you are trying to display the wizard in your toast, which I am not sure is possible.

You can do something like this instead:

```
<div id="app">

  <vs-toast></vs-toast>

  <vs-wizard :current-index.sync="currentStep">
      <vs-wizard-step 
        title="Personal Information" 
        description="Enter your details"
        :progress="progress.step1" 
        icon="person">
      </vs-wizard-step>
      <vs-wizard-step 
        title="Payment" 
        description="Pay with credit card or Paypal" 
        :progress="progress.step2"
        icon="credit-card">
      </vs-wizard-step>
      <vs-wizard-step 
        title="Confirmation" 
        description="Your order details" 
        :progress="progress.step3"
        :disable-previous="true"
        icon="check">
      </vs-wizard-step>
    </vs-wizard>
</div>
```

Comment: vue.js?3de6:523 [Vue warn]: Property or method "currentStep" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in root instance) I'm getting errors

Comment: You have to add 'currentStep' as data to your Vue instance. Also you have to create 'progress' computed property to provide feedback to the user on the completion of each of the steps within the wizard. Additionally you will need some sort of helper method that will calculate the completion percentage of each step. If you don't need the step completion feedback remove the progress attribute from the <vs-wizard-step>. Look at the modified answer above, specifically the Vue instance.